# Intersection of subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Given any ring $R$, prove that the intersection of an arbitrary collection of subrings of $R$ is also a subring of $R$.

Here is my attempt:

Suppose $R$ is an arbitrary ring. Let $S_{1},S_{2},...,S_{n}$ be subrings of $R$. Clearly $0_{R}\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}S_{i}$. Then if $x,y\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}S_{i}$, then $x,y\in S_{1},S_{2},...S_{n}$. Since each $S_{i}$ is closed under subtraction and multiplication, $x-y\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}S_{i}$, and $xy\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}S_{i}$. Hence, $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}S_{i}$ is a subring of $R$.

I believe that this is correct, but I was also thinking that since the trivial ring is a subring of $R$, i.e. $\{0_{R}\}\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}S_{i}$, then the only elements that could be in the intersection would be $0_{R}$. Any advice?

Comment: I not know what you’re asking exactly, but it looks like you are suggesting that he trivial ring is always one of the $S_i$, but of course that may not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I assume your rings are not required to have a unit.  If they are, you also need to mention $1_R$ being in all the subrings and thus in their intersection, and there is no "trivial subring".]

This is basically correct, but you have not considered an *arbitrary* collection of subrings.  What if your collection of subrings is infinite?  You can fix this by just not saying you have some set $C$ of subrings and not explicitly labelling the elements as $C=\{S_1,\dots,S_n\}$.

> I was also thinking that since the trivial ring is a subring of $R$, i.e. $\{0_{R}\}\in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}S_{i}$, then the only elements that could be in the intersection would be $0_{R}$.

That would be the case if you took the intersection of *all* the subrings of $R$, since $\{0_R\}$ is one such subring.  But you aren't necessarily intersecting all the subrings.  You are just taking *some* subrings and intersecting them, so the intersection may be larger.  (Also, your notation is incorrect: I think you mean to say $\{0_R\}\in \{S_1,\dots,S_n\}$.)

Comment: In the case where the collection of subrings is infinite,  how would I show that it is closed under subtraction and multiplication?  Couldn't I just write it in a similar manner saying something like, $$...x,y\in\bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty}S_{i}$$

Comment: Right, the proof is identical but you just have to not use notation that implies the collection is finite.  $\bigcap_{i=0}^\infty S_i$ is no good either, though, since it implies the collection is countable.  If $C$ is your collection, you can write the intersection as $\bigcap_{S\in C}S$, or simply $\bigcap C$.